# How should I install mathtools package using linux mint?

Tags: mathtools

I am trying to install the mathtools package using Linux Mint. My first attempt was via the Terminal: `sudo apt-get install mathtools` on which I got response

> Reading package lists...
>
> Done Building dependency tree...
>
> 0% Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package mathtools

Then I tried to install it manyally. I douwnloaded the zip file from here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools, then moved the folder into the latex directory, then create the mathtools.sty file by typing `tex mathtools.dtx`, and then the .sty file was into the right folder (the mathtools folder). However, when I tried to run my program the tex file still couldnt find it. Any ideas how to install the package? I need it for the \ceil and \floor functions?

Comment: I bet the packae is hidden in some meta package provided by your distribution. Is the `tlmgr` available on your system? Install it directly.

Comment: Please update you system as `mathtools` was part of some bundle some time ago. On a new TeX-distro, `mathtools` should be directly accessible. You could first try to run `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex3` in your terminal.

Comment: You should try with the ready-to-install `mathtools.tds.zip` that you'll find at the same place. All you'll have to do is unzip it at the root of your `texmf-local` directory, and ten run `mktexlsr`.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't already installed with your TeX installation? Did you try compiling a document with `\usepackage{mathtools}`? I'd be surprised if `mathtools` wasn't part of the default installation.

Comment: …you could always just install vanilla TeX Live… it's without a doubt a lot simpler (for just this very reason)

Answer (score 1):

The `mh` bundle contains mathtools. In Linux Mint open up the Synaptic Package Manager, enter your password and the then search: tex-live mh

Three packages come up. It's in `texlive-latex-recommended`. Click on the box to the left of it. Then press the Apply button.
[image]

Comment: There is no more an `mh` bundle. It was split last summer into `mathtools` and `breqn` with different maintainers.

Comment: @Bernard The tex-live version for Linux Mint isn't as current. In my Linux Mint distro mh is still mentioned in the notes for tex-live-latex-recommen.

Comment: @Bernard I've added a screenshot of what shows up.

Comment: You have an old version of TeX Live, which you should update. Can't you install the CTAN version of TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard: TL2013 in Linux Mint should be new enough for most people.

Comment: Each Linux distro has a repository of software that is "approved" (should not have conflicts with current system). It gets updated when those in charge update it. The alternative is to download a current version and put it in another directory. It's a hassle since your not automatically updated.

Comment: @DJP *In general*, you are quite correct. However, TeX Live is arguably an exception. There is a good case to be made for installing TeX Live from upstream. Generally speaking, it is easier to maintain, easier to update and less likely to spring nasty surprises than distro-packaged versions. If your distro's version suits your needs, fine. Your decision. But many people are better off using upstream's installer. (Note that the software is automatically installed into a location your distro's package manager does not use.) Upstream's setup has very many advantages.