# Is there any way to set up \ceil and \floor macros without installing the mathtools package?

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, tex-general

I can not install the `mathtools` package. Is there any way to create the `\ceil` and `\floor` macros without this package?

Comment: I would suggest to wait for a solution at [How should I install mathtools package using linux mint?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224244) before trying to hack things.

Comment: In any event, `mathtools` is only needed to make the floor and ceil a matched pair.  The individual glyphs are available (without packages) as `\lceil`, `\rceil`, `\lfloor`, and `\rfloor`.

Comment: These functions are not defined by `mathtools`, nor are they defined by any package I know. A `\floor` command can be defined, and `mathtools can help it to adapt automatically to the size of its contents. What is defined in basic LaTeX are de variable-sized delimiters `\lfloor`, `\rfloor`, `\lceil` and `\rceil`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need to load any packages to access the four macros `\lfloor`, `\lceil`, `\rfloor`, and `\rceil`. It is straightforward to use these macros to create two new macros called, say, `\floor` and `\ceil`:

```
\newcommand\floor[1]{\lfloor#1\rfloor}
\newcommand\ceil[1]{\lceil#1\rceil}
```

Then, write something such as `$\floor{x}$` and `$\ceil{y}$` in the body of the document.

---

*Addendum* to address @Teepeemm's follow-up comment: To create the option to resize the heights of the symbols produced by `\floor` and `\ceil`, I suggest using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro of the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\begin{document}
$\floor{x}$, $\ceil{y}$, $\floor*{\frac12}$, $\ceil*{\frac12}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also add `\left` and `\right` so that they resize according to their contents.